# VB6 Auto-Click Program Starts but Doesn't Stop

Tags: vb6, mouseevent

I'm writing an auto-click program in VB6. The idea is that, if I hold down left click while holding down right click at the same time, it begins clicking automatically until you let go of either.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Dim lefter As Boolean, righter As Boolean
Public Sub LeftClick()
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
    lefter = False
    righter = False
    Timer1.Interval = 80
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
If GetAsyncKeyState(2) = 0 Then
    righter = False
Else: righter = True
End If
If GetAsyncKeyState(1) = 0 Then
    lefter = False
Else: lefter = True
End If
If lefter = True Then
    If righter = True Then
        LeftClick
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Timer1 fires off every 80 milliseconds.

The thing works great until I try to stop it by releasing left click (while continuing to hold right click), which the program seems to completely ignore once it's started.

Relatively speaking, it's hardly a problem and it's easy to work around, but I'd rather fix it so that I wouldn't have to work around it at all.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `GetAsyncKeyState` [indicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) whether the key is currently down *and* whether it was pressed since the last call. If you simply need to know whether the key is currently down, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Dim righter As Boolean, lefter As Boolean
If GetAsyncKeyState(2) = 0 Then
    righter = False
Else: righter = True
End If
If GetAsyncKeyState(1) = 0 Then
    lefter = False
Else: lefter = True
End If
If lefter = True Then
    If righter = True Then
        LeftClick
    End If
End If
End Sub
Sub LeftClick()
  Debug.Print Timer & " LeftClick"
End Sub
```

Comment: The information is good, but the code didn't work; when I used that on my right click detector, it did nothing different, and when I used it on my left click detector, it no longer detected the left click :/

Comment: Really? I just tried it in my VB6 IDE and it works. Have edited my answer to show complete code. I added a trailing ampersand to the hexadecimal constant and I've explicitly declared the variables. Also you haven't posted your Declare for the API call - check that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you add:

```
Debug.Print Rnd
```

To your `Public Sub LeftClick()`, you'll notice that it's firing when it's supposed to.  You'll have to seek a different method of sending mouse events.

Comment: Oh, no, the problem wasn't that I couldn't get the program to start -- the problem was that I couldn't get it to stop. By releasing left click while still holding down right click (an action I'd need to do), the program would keep clicking even though left click was no longer down.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
If GetAsyncKeyState(1) And GetAsyncKeyState(2) Then LeftClick
```

Comment: That was my first attempt, but the program clicks once automatically and then stops.

Comment: I just did this and it seemed to work.  My guess is that LeftClick is interfering.